# Could someone please confirm my answer this Maclaurin series??

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find three nonzero terms of the Maclaurin series of the function

$f(x)={3/5} tan5x/x$

Using the maclaurin series i found them to be..

$3/5+x^2/25+2x^4/25$

Is this correct? If not what is the answer so I can find out where i went wrong. Im pretty sure its wrong

Thanks for any help

Comment: The tag [tag:euler-maclaurin] is not meant for questions about Maclaurin series. Please use the tag [tag:taylor-expansion] in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be wrong.

Consider $$\tan(y)=y+\frac{y^3}{3}+\frac{2 y^5}{15}+O\left(y^7\right)$$ Replace $y$ by $5x$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: once ive replaced y do I just simplify?

Comment: I suppose that this is what to do.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici Ok I did that and im not sure my answer is correct, Im obviously missing something.

Comment: Ive returned two separate answers, which is correct? $3+25x^2+250x^4$ and $5+125/3*x^2+1250/5*x^4$

Comment: You cannot get two different results. Write your rexpression using the result for $\tan(5x)$ from $\tan(y)$ with $y=5x$ and adjust the coefficients. One of your two answers is correct. Now, your turn !